# What does 'The documentary American Factory looks at' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of verb 'look at' in 'The documentary American Factory looks at'?

> The documentary American Factory looks at a former American automobile factory now operating as a Chinese business.

VOA Article: [Obamas and Netflix Present 1st Joint Film Project, ‘American Factory’](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/obamas-and-netflix-present-first-joint-project-with-film-american-factory-/5054769.html)

Comment: examines, journalistic usage.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "looks at" has a meaning part-way between "[shows](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/show)" and "[investigates](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/investigate)".  This meaning is close to the meaning of "[looks into"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/look-into).